# Health of my hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have a server in Linux, a while ago. I started to see the state of the disks, and I see that one, although already having 11 thousand hours of use, do, does not have any errors. Do I have to think about changing it or does it still last longer? I don't know much about it.

The disks are on 24 hours 7 days, it is a server.

Attached pictures:

Picture #1
[image: image 1]

Picture #2
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any drives with only 11,000 hours on them. All have far more.

I have a drive with 64,000+ hours and another with 55,000+ hours, both WD. Both are working well with no SMART warnings or errors. Both run 24/7 but are not in servers. I have another with over 64,000 hours but the Reallocated Sector Count is 5. The drive is over 16 years old. I also have a drive purchased in 1998, yes 1998. It isn't in regular use any more but when I last checked a few months ago it had no SMART warnings or errors and worked well.

In my view the life expectancy of a drive that hasn't been abused is more determined by luck then anything else. I would consider the "Reallocated Sector Count" and "Current Pending Sector" counts as of more importance than the power on hours. In your case both are zero.

Of course be sure you make regular backups. Any drive, old or new, can fail at any time and often without warning or apparent cause.

Answer (score 0):

> already having 11 thousand hours of use

That's barely over a year. If it hasn't died *yet*, then it should last another decade or so.

(For example, I don't know about the different WD sub-brands, but last week I replaced a pair of what looked like WD "Re" disks just because they were beginning to make annoying rattling noises after *ten years* of 24/7 service, and they still had 0 errors logged.)

However, even though it doesn't need replacement now, setting up e.g. a basic RAID 1 mirror would save you some worries, as it would allow the disk to be replaced *when* it fails – even without taking down the system at all.